# Sending X.509 certificates to WCF c#

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have a WCF service which uses such behaviors:

```
  <behavior name="WCFServiceCertificate.Service1Behavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <clientCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="ChainTrust"/>
        </clientCertificate>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="localhost" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
```

It uses a certficate named "localhost" which I created by makecert. First I created Root Certification Authority and then a certificate. I generated also a client certificate which was saved in a file.

Then, I have a client application which consumes that webservice. App.config consists of:

```
 <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IWS">
                <security>
                    <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

And I load the cerificate for client from a file:

```
  X509Certificate2 client = new X509Certificate2("client.pfx", "pass");
```

All certificates' stuff seem to be done properly, but when I want to invoke any service method from the client, it says:

> The caller was not authenticated by the service

Could someone, please, give me some advice on how to pass the certificate in SOAP header properly from the client to server? What do I miss?

Comment: How did you host you service? IIS, window service or self hosted? Have your installed your CA and certificate properly in Store?

Comment: The service is hosted on IIS. The certificates are done as described here: http://www.jayway.com/2014/09/03/creating-self-signed-certificates-with-makecert-exe-for-development/ I would appreciate any suggestions..

Comment: Have you configure your IIS to use that certificate?

Comment: What I want to achive is that the client uses a cerificate when sends requests to the server. The server authorises those requests. There is no need for the server to be authorised on client's side. Could you explain if I have to configure something more in IIS if I use message authorization?

Comment: Try this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18601/An-easy-way-to-use-certificates-for-WCF-security. May be it could help.

Answer (score 0):

Working with certificate is not an easy task specially for debugging it in WCF. For this reason you may consider the following steps to narrow down your problem.

1. Does your Service run after you embed certificate? One way to test if it is working properly is to try hitting your service in your browser.

   Ex. http://localhost/Path/Service.svc
2. Are you accessing the service address in your client same as what is describe in CN=localhost certificate?

   Ex. http://location/Path/Service.svc

   And not this :

   Ex. http://computername/Path/Service.svc

   Or

   Ex. http://computername.domain.com/Path/Service.svc

   Explanation :

   Certificate will not work if the name in the Common Name of certificate is different in the URL name issued to that certificate.
3. Are you in the same machine? Certificate with CN=localhost will only work in same machine.
4. Since you host your Service in IIS you need to configure your IIS to use the certificate you created and bind it in port 443.

   How?

   1. Go to you IIS and Client Default Web Site
   2. Click Binding location at the right side
   3. If protocol HTTPS is already configure try to edit it and assign your certificate. If not, Add the protocol HTTPS with port 443 and assign your certificate. Certificate should visible in the list if you installed properly in the store.

Through these steps we may able to know where to start. It could be at service problem, client problem or IIS configuration. Hope this will help us both to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling with the issue all the time. I reconfigured both client and the server side.

Web.config (server):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpEndpointBinding">
          <security>
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="WSInfo.WS" behaviorConfiguration="WCFServiceCertificate.Service1Behavior">
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpEndpointBinding" contract="WSInfo.IWS">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WCFServiceCertificate.Service1Behavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="ChainTrust"/>
            </clientCertificate>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="ForServer"
                                storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                                storeName="My"
                                x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And app.config (WinForms Client App):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text"
          textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
            enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
              algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IWS">
          <security>
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX:XX/WSInfo/WS.svc" behaviorConfiguration="CustomBehavior"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService1"
        contract="WSInfo.IWS" name="WSHttpBinding_IWS">
        <identity>
          <dns value="ForServer" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CustomBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate findValue="Client" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My" />
            <serviceCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="ChainTrust"/>
            </serviceCertificate>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I generated certificates in an application called XCA. First, on the server I generated the root cerificate and a certficate for client. I exported it and imported on client machine. Then I generated the root certificate on the client machine and the next certificate for server. I exported it and imported in server's system. I think the configuration files are OK, but maybe something's wrong with certificates - when I want to invoke a method from the client I get "The caller was not authenticated by the service". I tried to add HTTPS with my certificate but it resulted in problems with connection to IIS. Now IIS is off... I'll look up the solution but please verify if my configs are OK.